# MVC Html.DropDownListFor not binding on selecting the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a state drop down in my MVC application and calling an helper method to populate the dropdown. On selecting the same value more than one time, drop down is getting reset to the default value "Select State", instead of the correct state.

HTML View

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pat.StateId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Pat.StateId, listHelper.GetState(Model.Pat.StateId))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pat.StateId)
</div>
```

Helper code

```
        public static IList<SelectListItem> GetStateOptions(int? selectedId = null)
        {
            var lookupService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IConstantsHelper>();
            var result = lookupService.GetAll<State>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Text,
                Selected = selectedId.HasValue && selectedId == x.Id
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
            result.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select state...", Disabled = true, Selected = result.Any(x => !x.Selected)});
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You select from drop down it works, open the drop down again and select the same item and it resets to null? Can you explain more...

Comment: **the same value more than one time, drop down is getting reset** Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: If you put `@(Model.Pat.StateId)` somewhere, does it show the value that you would expect?

Comment: You can this with jquery.

Comment: Your `Selected = selectedId.HasValue && selectedId == x.Id` line of code is pointless. The `Selected` property is ignored when you bind to a model property - its the value of the property that determines what is selected

Comment: And why in the world do you have `result.Insert(...)` - Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Pat.StateId, listHelper.GetState(Model.Pat.StateId), "Select state...")`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your `.Any` condition, because there will be non selected options in your list, so it will return true.

Try changing it to:

```
result.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select state...", Disabled = true, Selected = !result.Any(x => x.Selected)});
```